# compiz moves wine windows

Tags: 11.10, compiz, wine

Since Ubuntu 11.10 compiz does not position wine menues correct but moves them to the screen's right corner.

screenshot 1 : http://media.cdn.ubuntu-de.org/forum/attachments/3900002/Bildschirmfoto.png

screenshot 2 : http://media.cdn.ubuntu-de.org/forum/attachments/3900002/Bildschirmfoto2.png

Does anybody know how to work around?

Comment: Is that WINE? Are you using Windows or a Windows Theme?

Comment: This is only a theme.(avant window navigator and compiz) I can see this Wine error  when  i use unity too. If i use metacity everything is right.

Comment: I too have problems with Wine and Unity. I find that when I maximise and restore a Wine window, it resets correctly; but that is always just a temporary solution.

Comment: If i usecompiz 0.8.6 this error doesn't exist why ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this annoying behaviour.

You have to install compizconfig-settings-manager

Open it and go to "Window decoration" and click the "Reset setting to the default value" in "Command".

The new command should be: /usr/bin/compiz-decorator

After this every new Window opens in it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCH8g.png

Comment: thx for the answer but it doesn't change anything .When i disable window decorations in ccsm (compizconfig-settings-manager) the error still exists.

Comment: Don't disable window decorations. You only have to click the button "Reset setting to the default value". Then, close Compiz config manager, and it should be fixed.

Comment: But it isn't.Some wimdows are placed nearly at the correct position. But not all Screenshot :  http://bluedxca93.freeunix.net/error.jpg